# Xamarin does not recognise any project anymore

Tags: xamarin

Today I was working on several projects and nothing wrong. Suddenly Xamarin does not understand any project anymore. Nothing changed at all. It just says I'm making errors.

```
using Android.OS;       
using Android.App;     
using Android.Widget;   
using Android.Graphics; 

[ActivityAttribute(Label = "Hello", MainLauncher = true)]
public class HelloApp : Activity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle b)
{
    MainActivity.OnCreate(base, b);

    TextView screen;
    screen = new TextView(this);
    screen.Text     = "Hello!";
    screen.TextSize = 80;
    screen.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
    screen.SetTextColor      (Color.DarkBlue);

    this.SetContentView(screen);
    }
}
```

so 'b' parameter name differs in base declaration. The name name 'MainActivity' does not exist in the current context. Use of the keyword 'base' is not valid in this context.

It doesn't matter what I make, what (what was working) project I am in. Nothing works anymore. Has anyone got any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```